# Web intent plugin in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I building [Bookmarks manager](https://myfavs.in) app in Nativescript. i am looking for a plugin related to web intent, but i could find any. If any one have any idea to achieve similar functionality like this [React native plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share-extension) for intent, Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straight forward on Android, you would use [JavaProxy](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity) to create an activity Or simply use your NativeScript activity if you want to open your application itself upon sharing, add the same `intent-filter` under that activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

With iOS, there is an [option feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3965) for building app extensions. But still there are some POCs for app extensions available on [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/tree/master/examples/TodayExtension) which seems to require some manual steps as mentioned in the Github issue.

Comment: Thank you very much manoj. If you have code, could you please share same. It will will be very helpful for me. I am very new to nativescript.